# SQL simulating Auto increment field

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, azure-sql-database

We are about to move our website to windows azure and faced a problem with sql-azure. They are not supporting the identity increment property due to a performance optimization.
Hence we have to design our own logic to support the existing feature in generating sequential identity.

So to generate unique sequential value we get the max(value) from the ID field of the table and increment it by 1 to insert a new record.

We now have to manage concurrent transactions, hence checked with isolation levels. 
However none of the isolation level lock the table to avoid reading the max value under concurrency.

Any help on locking a table or comment about this method would be very helpful. If some of you have already overcome this problem in a nice way, then can you please share.. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are aware this will scale pretty badly. There is a reason this is generally implemented in the rdbms. A better approach might be to use something like a guid.

Comment: A GUID, especially one generated randomly is a very bad for a primary key since it results in the table being heavily fragmented.  A GUID is also way wider than necessary for 99.9% of the use cases.

Comment: Using GUID in SQL Azure is not as bad as other RDMS and is the recommended solution by Microsoft.

Comment: You could use a sequence: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following procedure to increment a value stored in a separate table.  Putting an exclusive lock on the main table will result in horrible concurrency issues.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextID](
    @IDName nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
    /*
        Description:    Increments and returns the LastID value from tblIDs for a given IDName
        Author:         Max Vernon / Mike Defehr
        Date:           2012-07-19

    */

    DECLARE @Retry int;
    DECLARE @EN int, @ES int, @ET int;
    SET @Retry = 5;
    DECLARE @NewID int;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WHILE @Retry > 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            UPDATE dbo.tblIDs 
            SET @NewID = LastID = LastID + 1 
            WHERE IDName = @IDName;

            IF @NewID IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SET @NewID = 1;
                INSERT INTO tblIDs (IDName, LastID) VALUES (@IDName, @NewID);
            END
            SET @Retry = -2; /* no need to retry since the operation completed */
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF (ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205) /* DEADLOCK */
                SET @Retry = @Retry - 1;
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                SET @Retry = -1;
                SET @EN = ERROR_NUMBER();
                SET @ES = ERROR_SEVERITY();
                SET @ET = ERROR_STATE()
                RAISERROR (@EN,@ES,@ET);
                END
        END CATCH
    END
    IF @Retry = 0 /* must have deadlock'd 5 times. */
    BEGIN
        SET @EN = 1205;
        SET @ES = 13;
        SET @ET = 1
        RAISERROR (@EN,@ES,@ET);
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT @NewID AS NewID;
END
GO
```

(For completeness, here is the table associated with the stored proc)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblIDs]
(
    IDName nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LastID int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblIDs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [IDName] ASC
    ) WITH 
    (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        , FILLFACTOR = 100
    ) 
);
GO
```

Every time you want to obtain a new ID to use in the main table, you simply `EXEC GetNextID 'TableIDField';`

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, +1. Won't it result in out of order records in some cases? You may obtain a new id but then hold on to it while doing some other work and another process which obtained its id later may insert the main record first.

Comment: True, however if the field you're inserting the ID into is the primary key, the order will be fixed anyway.

Comment: That's right. That's probably a fairly minor thing anyway unless you rely on the order being always increasing.

Comment: What I meant is the order *would* be always increasing.  The engine would insert the lesser value before the greater value if the field is a PK.

Comment: I meant the logical order, not physical order of records. Let's say your is an invoice id which should increase, i.e. ivoices created later should have higher number than those created earlier.

Comment: Simply get the ID value just prior to writing the row, and problem solved.

Comment: @Max Hope yours would be an optimized solution compared to Guids(though thats another good solution). I just have to write an SP to achieve yours. I will suggest our team to go ahead in this. Thanks Szymon and Max for a good discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something similar this way

1. Start a transaction (in read committed transaction isolation level).
2. Select the max existing value with exclusive lock in `SELECT` query (`(XLOCK)` hint).
3. Update the value to be increased by 1.
4. Commit transaction.

Putting exclusive lock into the select statement will lock all other processes that will want to read the ID at the same time. They will have to wait until the transaction is finalised and  will read the new value if the transaction was committed.

---

As pointed out by Max Vernon below, this approach *may* not be suitable for high volume, highly concurrent systems. It may result in deadlocks as well (though possibility of deadlocks is not limited to this solution).

Comment: After select query with xlock execution and before the transaction ends, if there is an unexpected termination happened unfortunately, then should the table be in locked state. Will that require manual intervention to release the lock from lock table?

Comment: No, the transaction rollback will release the lock.

Comment: Actually am not doing it in a  stor proc. Am initiating the transaction and holding the tran id and supplying it for every sql stmt execution finally after 3 or 4 statement executions, I commit or rollback. I afraid if the network disconnection after first statement execution.

Comment: Network disconnection will close the connection to the database which will roll back the transaction (the transaction will have to be completed snd it's not marked as committed so will be rolled back).

Comment: Using an XLOCK is problematic for a highly concurrent system such as a website, or a line-of-business app used by many people simultaneously.  Also, this approach may create deadlocks in a busy system.

Comment: True, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

** Not a Sql Answer ** 
In the past I've solved similar situations by passing the ID into the insert.

To make sure it is the correct id you have a service exposed that runs on one box that just returns an integer from memory that is auto incremented after every request.

Should the service go down, fetch the max id from your table, increment and start handing out the Id's again.

This functions very similarly to a queue.

Comment: Do you use lock in handling mutual exclusion with the id generation code in your service.